# custom array.sort function with several criteria incl. boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that i would like to order by several properties.

Im going to showcase a single element of the array

```
var ele = {
    id: INT, various,
    priority: INT 1 - 10,
    shooterid: INT various,
    targetid: INT various,
    flight: BOOL
}
```

i would like to order the array according to some criteria and i can do the sort by priority, shooter and target by using

```
if (a.priority != b-priority){
  return a-priority - b-priority;
else if a.shooterid != b.shooterid){
  return a.shooterid - b. shooterid
}
else return a.targetid - b.targetid
```

However, i also want to sort by flight and i would like to all elements with `flight = true` to be sorted LAST in **addition** to the above sort.

I tried `if (a.flight){return -1/0/1}` a the very top of the above if/self (adding else to the formerly if) but it didnt work...

How can i extend the sort to include for the BOOL prop ?

Comment: please add some small sample data.

Comment: Just make the `flight` comparison the first thing you do. If the `flight` properties are different, then nothing else matters. You say that "didn't" work, but it *will* work; describe what went wrong or else nobody can really help you.

Comment: Did you literally the try the code `return -1/0/1`? That's negative `Infinity` (negative one divided by zero divided by one) -- is that what you intended? Or do you mean you tried each of those values separately and nothing worked?

Comment: You still need to compare the `flight` like anything else, because if you return any value unconditionally when `flight` is true then you can’t compare *within* the list of elements that have `flight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine all sort criteria with logical or `||`, even the boolean values.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, flight: true, priority: 1, shooterid: 2, targetid: 1 }, { id: 1, flight: true, priority: 2, shooterid: 2, targetid: 3 }, { id: 2, flight: false, priority: 1, shooterid: 1, targetid: 2 }, { id: 3, flight: false, priority: 2, shooterid: 1, targetid: 1 }, { id: 4, flight: true, priority: 1, shooterid: 1, targetid: 2 }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (
        a.flight - b.flight ||
        a.priority - b.priority ||
        a.shooterid - b.shooterid ||
        a.targetid - b.targetid
    );
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` should be:

```
if (a.flight != b.flight)
  return a.flight - b.flight;
```

In the subtraction, boolean `true` will be treated as `1` and `false` as `0`. That means that the `false` ones will sort before the `true` ones, as you say you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to approve the other answer because it looks clean with || instead of if/else. However, i appreciate your explanation on the reasoning.